# How to get absolute Xpath in inspect.exe

Tags: xpath, inspect

I'm using inspect.exe to spy web application ,i need to get absolute xpath in mouse over element but i did't get any xpath option.please help me to get xpath or any unique element identifier

**like this**

html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghjd6.png)/section/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghjd6.png)/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghjd6.png)

Please check Sample image i'm getting from inspect.exe while mouseover event

[image]

After Edit:

Please Check Below Image...

[image]

I'm using selenium to find element and click element  Based on Xpath. The xpath for select mouse over elements is.

**//*[@id="wrap"]/div/section/div[3]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghjd6.png)/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghjd6.png)/a**

My question is how to get Unique value from selected element or Xpath in Inspect.exe.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML containing the element?

Comment: @LucasWieloch,Thanks for your response.sorry for delay,This is web site i used [link](https://www.manualslib.com/brand/A.html).

Comment: I'm sorry but can you provide even more information, like which element do you need? Maybe more details on your problem exactly? Have you tried any xpath?

Comment: @LucasWieloch,please check my Edited Post.